# destructor giving "may be used uninitialized" for deleting resource

Tags: c++, warnings, destructor

The code below is a basic class to simulate an array.

The destructor is giving a warning with g++:

```
warning: ‘*((void*)(&<anonymous>)+8).s_array<int>::my_array’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       delete [] my_array;
```

Am I setting this up the wrong way?  Using the variable "initialized" like this is how I've done this in the past, with no warnings.

```
template<class TYPE>
class s_array{
private:
  int my_size;
  TYPE * my_array;
  bool initialized;

public:

  s_array(){initialized=false;}
  s_array(int size){
    initialized=true;
    my_size=size;
    my_array=new TYPE[my_size];
  }

  s_array(const s_array& source){
    if (source.initialized==true){
      initialized=true;
      my_size=source.my_size;
      my_array=new TYPE[my_size];
      for (int i=0; i<my_size; i++)
       my_array[i]=source.my_array[i];
    }
    else
      initialized=false;
  }
  s_array& operator= (const s_array& source){
    if (&source!=this){
      if (source.initialized==true){
       initialized=true;
       my_size=source.my_size;
       my_array=new TYPE[my_size];
        for (int i=0; i<my_size; i++)
         my_array[i]=source.my_array[i];
      }
      else
    initialized=false;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  ~s_array(){
    if (initialized)
      delete [] my_array;
  }
    TYPE operator [](int i) const    {
      assert(i>=0 && i<my_size);
      return my_array[i];
    }
    TYPE & operator [](int i) {
      assert(i>=0 && i<my_size);
      return my_array[i];
    }

};
```

In particular, is there something about the flow with initialized that is preventing the compiler from seeing that it corresponds to the my_array being initialized?

Comment: Why do you need a separate `bool` flag? It is much easier, and clearer, to simply initialize the pointer to `nullptr` if no initialization is necessary. After all, this is what `nullptr` is for. And, it will be easier for your compiler's optimizer to avoid spurious warnings.

Comment: Skip the `initialized` variable, use `my_array` instead. Initialize it to `nullptr` and check for that instead. Remember that it's okay to `delete[] nullptr`.

Comment: On another note, [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is a *macro* that will not do anything if `NDEBUG` is defined (common for release builds). That, together with the fact that it will forcibly abort the program if the assert fails, makes it pretty bad for run-time checks. Use an `if` check and throw an exception instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm fixed it by using nullptr as suggested instead of "initialized".  (Strangely, though, the compiler gives this warning inconsistently, even when I keep "initialized").

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
The reason I'm using assert here is that this is a scientific application where speed is paramount, and I want a class that has the speed of an array, but where I can check for bound errors while programming and debugging.

The class as defined has these features (with NDEBUG turned on, I am matching the speed I get with pure arrays).

Is there a better way to accomplish these two goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler sees that if you create an object using the default constructor, then `my_array` is not initialised. A default constructed object can be destroyed, and in the destructor you access the value of `my_array` which would have undefined behaviour if it is not initialised.

Sure, you may have established an invariant that `initialized` is only true if `my_array` is initialised, but the compiler will not be able to prove that.

---

You can simplify your class by removing the `initialized` member, and replace all its comparisons with comparing `my_array` to `nullptr` (except the one in the destructor; that check becomes redundant), and initialise `my_array` to `nullptr` in the default constructor. The latter change solves the warning.